# FormData sends boolean as string to server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, multipartform-data, form-data

I have the following input which is a toggle returns true , false

```
<input id="{{event.id}}" ng-model="event.is_active" type="checkbox" value="true" class="block__input" ng-class="{'input__toggle--active' :  event.is_active}">
```

and when I send it like this

```
 var formData = new FormData();
            console.log(scope.event.is_active);
            formData.append('is_active', scope.event.is_active);
```

In the server I receive false and true as strings 'true', 'false'

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 10):

`FormData` will always be sent as strings. One way to solve the problem is to use JSON. Simply encode your values with `JSON.stringify` on the clientside. On serverside you simply decode the values.

**Clientside**

```
var fd = new FormData;
var data = {
    name: 'john doe',
    active: true,
    count: 42
};
var prop;
for(prop in data){
    fd.append(prop, JSON.stringify(data[prop]));
}

// if you want to upload files, too
fd.append('file', file);

$http({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/api/upload',
    data: fd,
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers:{ 'Content-Type': undefined }
});
```

**Serverside (PHP, simplified)**

```
$data = [];
foreach($_POST as $prop => $value){
    $data[$prop] = json_decode($value);
}
// $data contains the correct values now ..
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have a problem with boolean you need to send `0` or `1`.

Example:

```
let data = new FormData()
data.append('type', '0')
data.append('typeSend', '1')
```

In many cases, the server will understand that this is a bool value: `false = 0`, `true = 1`

Comment: This should not be used. The official typing from `lib.dom.ts` has the value argument as `value: string | Blob`, so `number` is not a valid argument.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, wher you see number in this answer ? If you dont like "0" and "1", you may do String(0) and String(1), Numbers that are quoted are strings

Comment: This is an old answer, and as you can see [the edit was made to make the values strings instead of numerical values](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51222349/revisions)

Answer (score 4):

You could send each "checked item" as a string (which results in true) and not send the "unchecked items" (which could default to false on the server side.) For example:

Client Side (js/jquery)

```
var fd = new FormData();
var foo = $('[name="foo"]').prop('checked');
var bar = $('[name="bar"]').prop('checked');
var is_active = $('[name="is_active"]').prop('checked');

if (foo) fd.append('foo',foo);
if (bar) fd.append('bar', bar);
if (is_active) fd.append('is_active', is_active')
```

Server Side (php/laravel)

```
$foobar = new FooBar();
$foobar->foo = $request->foo ? true : false;
$foobar->bar = $request->bar ? true : false;
$foobar->is_active = $request->is_active ? true : false;
```

The ternary statements above will return false on null in php.

Answer (score 1):

use `JSON.stringify` on client to send numbers and boolean values, then parse it on bakend

```
const form = new FormData;
const data = {
    name: 'john doe',
    active: true,
    count: 42
};

form .append('file', file); // send your file here
form .append('fileProps', JSON.stringify(data));

// then send form with POST from angular with using http
```

Answer (score 1):

`FormData.append(..)` or `FormData.set(..)` converts values always to string (except if its Blob), see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append):

> If the sent value is different than String or Blob it will be automatically converted to String:

```
formData.append('name', true);
formData.append('name', 74);
formData.append('name', 'John');

formData.getAll('name'); // ["true", "74", "John"]
```

So you could use json encode/decode as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/39094808/2311074

However, if its just that single value and you know it has to be a boolean but will be sent as a string, you may also just convert it to boolean on the server-side:

```
$is_active = ($this->request->is_active == 'true') ? true : false
```

Answer (score -2):

this is your `ng-model`:

`ng-model="event.is_active"`

so, why not use `ng-model="formData.event.is_active"` instead ?

then, in your script file, you can directly send `$scope.formData` as an object to the server.

Answer (score -3):

`formData.append('is_active', scope.event.is_active === 'true');`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10154497)

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't provide an answer? I think it solves the author's problem.

Comment: becuase you just post a code without any explaination of it .. this could be post as a comment