# How to append boolean type values in formdata?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, boolean, form-data

Here I have `this.state.word is boolean type` so value is in `true/false`

but when I want to try to append `this.state.word` it gives me error like this `argument type boolean is not assignable to parameter type string | blob`

so how to append boolean type values(true/false) in formdata( NOTE :- I want to send in boolean type not in string) ?

```
handleSendSynopsis() {
  const data = new FormData();
  data.append('word', this.state.word);
}
```

Comment: try converting it to string like this: `String(this.state.word)`

Comment: @VaibhavVishal I want to send in boolean type not in string

Comment: but it wants a string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FormData sends boolean as string to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33625248/formdata-sends-boolean-as-string-to-server)

Answer (score 15):

use JSON.stringify on the client to send numbers and boolean values, then parse it on the backend

For Example

```
const form = new FormData;
const data = {
    name: 'john doe',
    active: true,
    count: 42
};

form .append('file', file); // send your file here
form .append('fileProps', JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: Is it not possible to send boolean values from here

Comment: Yes, formdata don't support data type: boolean, integer, you need to send it as string

Comment: @Akki, PLEASE ACCEPT THE ANSWER IF THAT HELPS

Comment: Yeh, form .append('fileProps', JSON.stringify(data)) is working

Answer (score 3):

According to [FormData Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append), `FormData.append` accepts only a `USVString` or a `Blob`. S you will have to convert your data to string and then parse it later on the backend. You can use `JSON.stringify` to convert your form object to a string.